# Dephi / Pascal Syntax (SAM Broadcaster PAL script) - How can I create a timestamp with millisecond object?

Tags: delphi, pascal

I'm a noob so please don't assume I know much. Feel free to let me know if I use incorrect termanology.

I have a function in a PAL script (based on Pascal / Delphi) in SAM broadcaster, radio automation software.

The function returns the time in milliseconds of Cue Point 1 in a database record related to a music file.

I wish to call this function's output in the body of my script as you might a variable. But it needs to be expressed as a hh:mm:ss timestamp.

Here is the function, which might have an output of 20000, for 20 seconds.

```
var CP : Integer = 0;

function ExtractCP(Song : TSongInfo):Integer;
var
P : Integer;
XFade : String;
begin
Result := -1;
XFade := Trim(Song['xfade']);

WriteLn('Decoding XFade string');
WriteLn('XFade: '+XFade);

if XFade = '' then
  Result := -1
else
  begin
   P := Pos('ct0=',XFade);  {Where 0 is the Custom Cue Point Number}
   if (P > 0) then
    begin
     Delete(XFade,1,P+2);
     P := Pos('&',XFade);
     if (P>0) then
      Delete(XFade,P,Length(XFade));

     Result := StrToIntDef(XFade,-1);

     WriteLn('CP time detected: '+XFade);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Here is the implementation component.

```
   while (Song['songtype']='S') and (not Skip) do
        begin   
         VAR DT : DateTime;
         VAR frac : Float;
         VAR hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds : Integer;
         hours := 24;
         minutes := 60;
         seconds := 60;
         milliseconds := 1000;

     // 1 millisecond as fractional part of a day
     frac := 1.0 / hours / minutes / seconds / milliseconds;
     frac := frac * cp;

     dt := Now + DateTime (frac); {Wait for Cue Point 0}
     WriteLn(DateTimeToStr(dt));
     PAL.WaitForTime(DT);
     Skip := True;
    end;
```

I guess my question is a simple one.

Calculated variable 'cp' is not being imported, how to I correctly call the result of the function in the line...

```
 frac := frac * cp;
```

I have had help here (for full background, including timestamp calculation methodology and entire script)...

http://support.spacialaudio.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=40795&start=15

Comment: There's a large wall of code. And your comments indicate that CP always has value -1 and you want it to have a different value. The large wall of code contains nothing that writes to CP. So, what are we to do? Did you post the wrong code? Please try and work out what the crux of your problem is and post a question that concentrates exclusively on that. If that means you cut down the code to a small reproduction of the problem, then so much the better. -1

Comment: just try changing       Delete(XFade,1,P+2)  to    Delete(XFade,1,P+3);

Comment: You have exactly two locations that access `cp`. The first is where it's declared and initialized to zero: `var CP : Integer = 0;`. The second is where you use that zero as a multiplier: `frac := frac * cp;`, which if course produces `zero`. What exactly do you want us to tell you about it other than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming XFade contains a String like 'ABC ct0=1234&'
`Delete(XFade,1,P+2);` will deliver '=1234&'

```
P := Pos('&',XFade);
     if (P>0) then
      Delete(XFade,P,Length(XFade));
```

will deliver '=1234' which can not be convertet to an integer
So at least you will have to change `Delete(XFade,1,P+2);` to `Delete(XFade,1,P+3);`

the generation of dt can be shortened to

```
{ if not defined
Const
  MSecsPerDay= 24*60*60*1000;
}
cp := ExtractCP(Song);
if cp>-1 then
   begin
     dt := Now + CP / MSecsPerDay;
     .....
   end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.The function statement works correctly.

String...

&i=6649&ct0=3000&cn0=CPZERO

Returns 3000, which is what I want.

Comment: Update: OK thanks Bummi, even though `Delete(XFade,1,P+2);` correctly returned the value 3000 `Delete(XFade,1,P+3);` fixed it for me! And it was imported into the main equation as desired.

Thank you! I don't fully understand why. But I'll try to get me head round it.

Comment: I re-read your solution. Could it be that when the line was written (for the output using +3) the '=' was dropped (at leat visually)? Making me think I had returned the correct millisecond value, when I actually, as you say, didn't equate to an integer? That might make sense. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Regarding your optimisation, 'MSecsPerSec' is not something the SAM broadcaster compiler seems to understand, did I need to define it somewhere?

Comment: Ouuuppss, sorry ... that was a bad typo shoud have been MSecsPerDay, I did an edit. A constant is added, usualy found in sysutils.